# rev slider in woocommerce custom tabs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a site where I need to add rev slider in some custom tabs in woocommerce. 
But it works only with the first tab which gets open by default. I looked around but was not able to find a solution for this. What I got to know that as the content is hidden in other tabs when the page loads, so rev slider messes up.

So now I am trying to add the slider in the product-single template page. My only problem is, each product has a different slider.

I have made the slider as per their product name with the thought of dynamically calling them with something like this

```
<?php putRevSlider( 'the_title()' ); ?>
```

I tried some other similar ways too but its not working. I am new to php so please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way of doing this.
I ran an if else statement and its working as i need. I added this code in content-single-product template page.
Heres the code if someone faces the same problem

```
<?php
$MySliderTitle = get_the_title();
if ($MySliderTitle == 'Vertical Booking') {
?> <div class="myproductslider"> <?php putRevSlider( 'vertical-booking' ); ?> </div>
<?php
}
else if ($MySliderTitle == 'HotelRunner') {
?> <div class="myproductslider"> <?php  putRevSlider( 'hotelrunner' ); ?> </div>
<?php
}
else if ($MySliderTitle == 'Bookingsuite') {
?> <div class="myproductslider"> <?php  putRevSlider( 'booking-suite' ); ?> </div>
<?php
}
else if ($MySliderTitle == 'Quickbooks') {
?> <div class="myproductslider"> <?php  putRevSlider( 'quickbooks' ); ?> </div>
<?php
}
else if ($MySliderTitle == 'RepUp') {
?> <div class="myproductslider"> <?php  putRevSlider( 'repup' ); ?> </div>
<?php
}
else if ($MySliderTitle == 'Review Express') {
?> <div class="myproductslider"> <?php  putRevSlider( 'review-express' ); ?> </div>
<?php
}
else if ($MySliderTitle == 'Siteminder') {
?> <div class="myproductslider"> <?php  putRevSlider( 'siteminder' ); ?> </div>
<?php
}
else if ($MySliderTitle == 'Trip Connect') {
?> <div class="myproductslider"> <?php  putRevSlider( 'trip-connect' ); ?> </div>
<?php
}
else if ($MySliderTitle == 'Xero') {
?> <div class="myproductslider"> <?php  putRevSlider( 'xero' ); ?> </div>
<?php
}
?>
```